# Java Generics (bounded wildcards)

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard, effective-java, pecs

According to the book "Effective Java" of Joshua Bloch there is a rule about how/when use the bounded wildcards in generics. This rule is PECS (Producer-Extends, Comsumer-Super). When I study the following example:

```
Stack<Number> numberStack = new Stack<Number>();
Iterable<Integer> integers = ... ;
numberStack.pushAll(integers);
```

I understand that this rule fits perfect in this example. I have to declare the method `pushAll` as the following sample:

```
// Wildcard type for parameter that serves as an E producer
public void pushAll(Iterable<? extends E> src) {
    for (E e : src)
    {
       push(e);
    }  
}
```

But what happens if I have the following example?

```
Stack<Integer> integerStack = new Stack<Integer>();
Iterable<Number> numbers = ... ;
integerStack.pushAll(numbers);
```

I have to declare the `pushAll` as it follows:

```
public void pushAll(Iterable<? super E> src) {
    for (E e : src)
    {  
        push(e);
    }
}
```

According to **PECS** rule the above declaration is wrong. But I want to have a `Stack` of `Integer`s and pass to this `Stack` a `Number`. Why not to do it? 

Why should I always use the `extends` keyword? Why using `super` is wrong?

 Of course the same stands for the **comsumer**'s point of view. Why a **consumer** should always be `super`?

PS: To be more specific you can find this above example at the sector "*Item 28*" of the referred book.

Comment: when you push - you act as a counsumer, not a producer, so you need to use the super keyword.

Comment: According to the book I am producer. The comment "Wildcard type for parameter that serves as an E producer" is by the writter. The writer sais that I am a comsumer when I pull for the Stack! The first two samples are from the book (copy-paste). The third example is mine.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a `Stack<Foo>` you mean a Stack of Foos, or subclasses of Foo. As an example, you would expect to be able to put a `String` in a `Stack<Object>`. The other way is not true,  you should not be able to insert another Object, in a `Stack<String>`.

In your example you declare a `Stack<Integer>`. You should be able to put Integers in this stack, but not other Numbers (like a Double), which you would if you declared the parameter `<? super E>`. That's why the put-method should have a paramter of the type `<? extends E>`.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to store arbitrary numbers in a Stack can't possibly work, since a Number could be something other that an Integer. So your example doesn't make much sense.

You would use super when the object asts as a consumer, i.e. when instances of the generic type of the object are passed as arguments to methods of the object. For example:

```
 Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>)
```

In this example, the sort method takes T instances from the collection, and passes them as argument to the `compare(T o1, T o2)` of the comparator.

Contrast this to your first example, where the Iterable `src` is a producer. The `pushAll()` method calls a method of the Iterable which roduces (i.e. returns) instances of T. In this case, the iterable is a producer, hence the use of `? extends T`

Answer (score 0):

In the `pushAll` method, you are not passing type `E`, but any type that extends `E`. So, instead of passing an `Iterable` of `Number`s, you can pass any `Iterable` of a type that extends `Number`.

The original example uses a `Number` type because you can then pass any type that is a subclass of `Number`, like `Integer`, `BigDecimal` and so on.

In your example, you are doing it the other way around. You are using `Integer` to declare your `Stack`. Therefore, `pushAll` will only be able to accept those classes that are extended by `Integer`. You will not be able to use `Numbers` (or any other class, because `Integer` is a final class).

Answer (score 0):

First thing to notice is that Integer extends Number, so you shouldn't be pushing Number objects into a Stack of Integers. However, the first sample will work with Integers, Floats, BigDecimal and all other Number subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't make much sense. A construct like `<? extends Number>` means that Number and every type is allowed which inheits from Number. So you define an upper and a lower boundary, from type Number down to the most specific one. The other way round, `<? super Number>` means that Number and any of its supertyes are allowed. Since Number extends Object and implements Serializable the following three types are allowed:

1. java.lang.Number
2. java.lang.Object
3. java.io.Serializable

In your example you declare the generic type `Stack<Integer>`. Let's consider the following.

1. Your Stack is never be able to hold items of any **super type** of Integer
2. Your Stack is never be able to hold items of any **subtype** of Integer, since Integer class is final and thus it can't be subclassed.

So, if you want to declare the generic type `Stack<Integer>`, your iterable is of type `Iterable<Integer>` and thus your Stack can **only** hold items of type Integer. You are totally right with the mnemonic **PECS**, but this only works if you have choosen a concrete type which has at least one super type and at least one subtype.